# Angularjs 1 groupBy partial matching string

Tags: angularjs

I have a JSON object and I want to group the items even by partial matching.

```
var object = [
    {id: 1, items: "a, b, c, d"}, 
    {id: 2, items: "a, b, d, c"},
    {id: 3, items: "a, b, c, d, e"}
    {id: 4, items: "a, b, d, c, e"}
];
```

I would like to know if is possible by this rough example when I do per say :

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in object | groupBy: 'items' track by $index">
    {{value.length}}
</li>
```

I expect the output to be 2x **a, b, c, d** and 2x **a, b, c, d, e** but by default, the groupBy function only groups the items if the string match 100% so I will get 4x different groups.